# Google Analytics Behavior Flow Showing as Not Set

Tags: google-analytics

I have never ran into this issue before using behavior flow with GA, but most if not all the page groupings are showing up as not set which makes it unusable. Any idea why this might be or if this issue can even be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running any Google Ads campaigns, by any chance? Also, can you see which browser the (not set) data is primarily coming from?

Comment: I wanna say yes about ads. I personally don't oversee the ads thought. As far as seeing the browser I can't. Whenever I highlight or go into the group it just says not set